# Filtering multiple custom fields with WP REST API 2

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, rest-api

I want to filter posts based on multiple acf custom fields with AND relation. Something like this:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'product',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => 'color',
                'value'   => 'blue',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'price',
                'value'   => array( 20, 100 ),
                'type'    => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            ),
        ),
    );
```

I might even have more filters. How can I convert these to REST API 2 filters?

Comment: Take a look at this post and try to create your function
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169408/wp-json-rest-api-ryan-mccue-how-to-query-posts-with-specific-meta-data-with-a

Answer (score 6):

This solution works with [`get_items()`](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/develop/lib/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L81) in [`/lib/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php`](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/develop/lib/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php) of the [`v2 WP Rest API`](http://v2.wp-api.org).

---

First, you'll want to construct the [`GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) arguments like you would for a [`new WP_Query()`](https://generatewp.com/wp_query/). The easiest way to do this is with [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

```
$args = array (
    'filter' => array (
        'meta_query' => array (
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array (
                'key'     => 'color',
                'value'   => 'blue',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array (
                'key'     => 'test',
                'value'   => 'testing',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
$field_string = http_build_query( $args );
```

It'll produce something like:

`filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5Brelation%5D=AND&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=color&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=blue&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcompare%5D=%3D&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B1%5D%5Bkey%5D=test&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=testing&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B1%5D%5Bcompare%5D=%3D`

Which, if you want readable, you can also use Chrome tools and [`decodeURIComponent('your-query-here')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to make it a easier to read when you throw it into your [JSON Rest API URL](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/):

[`https://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/product?filter[meta_query][relation]=AND&filter[meta_query][0][key]=color&filter[meta_query][0][value]=blue&filter[meta_query][0][compare]==&filter[meta_query][1][key]=test&filter[meta_query][1][value]=testing&filter[meta_query][1][compare]==`](https://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/product?filter[meta_query][relation]=AND&filter[meta_query][0][key]=color&filter[meta_query][0][value]=blue&filter[meta_query][0][compare]==&filter[meta_query][1][key]=test&filter[meta_query][1][value]=testing&filter[meta_query][1][compare]==)

Note: To use your custom post type you would put `product` before `?`

`/wp-json/wp/v2/<custom-post-type>?filter[meta_query]`

---

So you have your query but we need to instruct WP how to handle a few things:

1. Adding REST support for the custom post type `product`
2. Allowing the query args `meta_query`
3. Parsing `meta_query`

---

```
// 1) Add CPT Support <product>


function wpse_20160526_add_product_rest_support() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    //be sure to set this to the name of your post type!
    $post_type_name = 'product';
    if( isset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type_name ] ) ) {
        $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->show_in_rest = true;
        $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_base = $post_type_name;
        $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_controller_class = 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller';
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse_20160526_add_product_rest_support', 25 );


// 2) Add `meta_query` support in the GET request

function wpse_20160526_rest_query_vars( $valid_vars ) {
    $valid_vars = array_merge( $valid_vars, array(  'meta_query'  ) ); // Omit meta_key, meta_value if you don't need them
    return $valid_vars;
}

add_filter( 'rest_query_vars', 'wpse_20160526_rest_query_vars', PHP_INT_MAX, 1 );


// 3) Parse Custom Args

function wpse_20160526_rest_product_query( $args, $request ) {

    if ( isset( $args[ 'meta_query' ] ) ) {

        $relation = 'AND';
        if( isset($args['meta_query']['relation']) && in_array($args['meta_query']['relation'], array('AND', 'OR'))) {
            $relation = sanitize_text_field( $args['meta_query']['relation'] );
        }
        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => $relation
        );

        foreach ( $args['meta_query'] as $inx => $query_req ) {
        /*
            Array (

                [key] => test
                [value] => testing
                [compare] => =
            )
        */
            $query = array();

            if( is_numeric($inx)) {

                if( isset($query_req['key'])) {
                    $query['key'] = sanitize_text_field($query_req['key']);
                }
                if( isset($query_req['value'])) {
                    $query['value'] = sanitize_text_field($query_req['value']);
                }
                if( isset($query_req['type'])) {
                    $query['type'] = sanitize_text_field($query_req['type']);
                }
                if( isset($query_req['compare']) && in_array($query_req['compare'], array('=', '!=', '>','>=','<','<=','LIKE','NOT LIKE','IN','NOT IN','BETWEEN','NOT BETWEEN', 'NOT EXISTS')) ) {
                    $query['compare'] = sanitize_text_field($query_req['compare']);
                }
            }

            if( ! empty($query) ) $meta_query[] = $query;
        }

        // replace with sanitized query args
        $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
    }

    return $args;
}
add_action( 'rest_product_query', 'wpse_20160526_rest_product_query', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a test i made on Localhost:

For security reasons meta query is not allowed on WP Api, first what you have to do is to add meta_query to allowed rest_query by adding this function on your wordpress theme `functions.php`

```
function api_allow_meta_query( $valid_vars ) {

  $valid_vars = array_merge( $valid_vars, array( 'meta_query') );
  return $valid_vars;
}
add_filter( 'rest_query_vars', 'api_allow_meta_query' );
```

after that you will need build the html query by using this function on the other website that will get the data from the wordpress website

```
$curl = curl_init();
$fields = array (
  'filter[meta_query]' => array (
    'relation' => 'AND',
      array (
        'key' => 'color',
        'value' => 'blue',
        'compare' => '='
      ),
      array (
        'key' => 'price',
        'value' => array ( 20, 100 ),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
      ),
    ),
  );

$field_string = http_build_query($fields);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array (
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://yourwordpreswebssite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?' . $field_string
  )
);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

echo htmlentities($result);
```

I change the fields array so the look now like your query arguments.
The encoded query string will look like this:

```
http://yourwordpreswebssite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter%5Btaxonomy%5D=product&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5Brelation%5D=AND&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=color&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=blue&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcompare%5D=%3D&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B1%5D%5Bkey%5D=price&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D%5B0%5D=20&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D%5B1%5D=100&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B1%5D%5Btype%5D=numeric&filter%5Bmeta_query%5D%5B1%5D%5Bcompare%5D=BETWEEN
```

By using `urldecode()`, which in this case will be: `urldecode('http://yourwordpreswebssite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?' . $field_string);` you will have an URL like this one:

```
http://yourwordpreswebssite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[taxonomy]=product&filter[meta_query][relation]=AND&filter[meta_query][0][key]=color&filter[meta_query][0][value]=blue&filter[meta_query][0][compare]==&filter[meta_query][1][key]=price&filter[meta_query][1][value][0]=20&filter[meta_query][1][value][1]=100&filter[meta_query][1][type]=numeric&filter[meta_query][1][compare]=BETWEEN
```

If you can provide us your live website URL so we can test it using postman directly on your website, because to test it on localhost or any existing WordPress site will be needed to create product custom post type and add meta fields etc etc. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have tested with the query as in the question on Postman and it didn't work.

Comment: @Dan i made some improvements on the solution, the filter values are same as your query arguments, including custom post type which was not specified in the previous solution.

Comment: We don't have `product` taxonomy. It works great! Didn't think about wrapping `meta_query` inside `filter` :)

Comment: @Dan I'm glad to hear it. I have wrote a post about it yesterday, you may consider sharing it :) [WordPress REST API with meta fields](http://www.shomtek.com/wordpress-rest-api-using-meta-fields/).

Comment: A couple things, on some AWS servers, using  [] as an array will kill the request. You should just use array() to be safe and for those how might copy/paste. Also, does this support the CPT product or only the taxonomy? And lastly, do you need to sanitize meta_query? Seeing that it was pulled, do you run a security risk by accepting anything a user supplies?

Comment: @Eduart I know how to make it works for myself base on your idea but you should edit the answer too.

Comment: @jgraup thnx a lot for your comment. I didn't know that fact about AWS servers. Custom post types and Custom taxonomy should be registered with REST API before and for sure validation should be used on input and escape on output. The reason why I didn't used sanitize is because i tested it only on output for custom fields that i had validated them before on input. But your right, it should be improved for other users that will only copy paste it.

Comment: Some AWS servers only allow PHP 5.3, which isn't great, but it is what it is. So it's a syntax error in 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

1. first add plugin or copy all code and paste all plugin in
   functions.php of this link
   https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter
2. use this

```
?filter[meta_query][relation]=AND
&filter[meta_query][0][key]=REAL_HOMES_property_price
&filter[meta_query][0][value][0]=10
&filter[meta_query][0][value][1]=10000001
&filter[meta_query][0][compare]=''
&filter[meta_query][1][key]=REAL_HOMES_property_price
&filter[meta_query][1][value]=10
&filter[meta_query][1][compare]='='
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without Rest API
Like this
(It is my posts filter)

```
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby' => 'date', // сортировка по дате у нас будет в любом случае (но вы можете изменить/доработать это)
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );

    // создаём массив $args['meta_query'] если указана хотя бы одна цена или отмечен чекбокс
    if( isset( $_GET['price_min'] ) || isset( $_GET['price_max'] ) || isset( $_GET['type'] ) )
        $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' ); // AND значит все условия meta_query должны выполняться


    if( $type ){
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'type',
            'value' => $type,
        );
    };

    if( $plan ){
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'plan',
            'value' => $plan,
        );
    };

    if( $room_num ){
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'room_num',
            'value' => $room_num,
        );
    };

    if( $etage ){
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'etage',
            'value' => $etage,
        );
    };  

    if( $price_min || $price_max ){
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => array( $price_min, $price_max ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        );
    };  

    if( $area_min || $area_max ){
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'area',
            'value' => array( $area_min, $area_max ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        );
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm really curious about doing it with REST API v2.

Comment: Well, i think, my variant is good, but if you want...The fact that my method is not limited to the parameters!

Answer (score 1):

In Wordpress 4.7 the `filter` argument has been removed.

You can reactivate it installing [this](https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter) plugin provided by the Wordpress team. Only after that you can use one of the solutions proposed in the other answers.

I've haven't found a solution to do the same without installing the plugin, yet.