# WP Rest API V2 OR Operator in URL

Tags: rest-api

Does anybody know if I can do an OR search in the URL like:

http://www.example.com/api/wp-json/wp/v2/books/?(filter[category_name]=anthropology&filter[category_name]=africa)|(filter[category_name]=anthropology&filter[category_name]=china)

(this example actually returns data but only the results for the second filter group (anthropology / china))

Any hints appreciated!

Comment: The `category_name` parameter takes a single string, and doesn't support an array as an argument, even if  you get an array out of this WP_Query won't support that, you'll need to pass in IDs instead and use `category__in`

Answer (score 0):

First (since 4.7.1) you will need to re-activate the `filter` parameter. 
Then make sure you have REST support activated for your custom post type (`books`).

Next you have to allowing the query args `meta_query` and parse it.

This answer shows how to do all this. Specifically, how to construct the meta query and the `compare` operators. : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/227869/111022