# How to make a WP REST API query with meta_query in WP4.7?

Tags: meta-query, rest-api, wp-api

There is no "filter" parameter in WP REST API WP 4.7 and this call doesn't work: http://domain.tld/wp-json/wp/v2/cpt_name?meta_query[0][key]=cf_name&meta_query[0][value][0]=cf_value1&meta_query[0][value][1]=cf_value2&meta_query[0][compare]=IN

Does anyone here know how to make a query via WP REST API in WP4.7?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226589/filtering-multiple-custom-fields-with-wp-rest-api-2/