# How to do a meta query using REST-API in WordPress 4.7+?

Tags: meta-query, rest-api

I am trying to filter by a meta query but no matter what I try I can not make it work.

Basically I want this query in through the rest API:

```
wp-json/wp/v2/books?meta_query[relation]=OR&meta_query[0][key]=arkivera&meta_query[0][value]=1&meta_query[0][compare]==
```

Ive tried several different custom fields but it will always return all post objects.

In my functions file I've added:

```
function api_allow_meta_query( $valid_vars ) {

  $valid_vars = array_merge( $valid_vars, array( 'meta_query') );
  return $valid_vars;
}
add_filter( 'rest_query_vars', 'api_allow_meta_query' );
```

I tried finishing some documentation regarding this but couldn't, also most of the similar questions are not for wordpress 4.7 since filter[xxx] is removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering multiple custom fields with WP REST API 2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226589/filtering-multiple-custom-fields-with-wp-rest-api-2)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write your own REST handler for custom queries if you want. In your case, the query can done by doing so:

```
// Register a REST route
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    //Path to meta query route
    register_rest_route( 'tchernitchenko/v2', '/my_meta_query/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET', 
            'callback' => 'custom_meta_query' 
    ) );
});

// Do the actual query and return the data
function custom_meta_query(){
    if(isset($_GET['meta_query'])) {
        $query = $_GET['meta_query'];
        // Set the arguments based on our get parameters
        $args = array (
            'relation' => $query[0]['relation'],
            array(
                'key' => $query[0]['key'],
                'value' => $query[0]['value'],
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        );
        // Run a custom query
        $meta_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if($meta_query->have_posts()) {
            //Define and empty array
            $data = array();
            // Store each post's title in the array
            while($meta_query->have_posts()) {
                $meta_query->the_post();
                $data[] =  get_the_title();
            }
            // Return the data
            return $data;
        } else {
            // If there is no post
            return 'No post to show';
        }
    }
}
```

Now, all you have to do is to access:

```
wp-json/tchernitchenko/v2/my_meta_query?meta_query[relation]=OR&meta_query[0][key]=arkivera&meta_query[0][value]=1&meta_query[0][compare]==
```

Comment: Is there a way to extend this to WooCommerce Legacy API?

Answer (score 20):

Use filter [rest_{CUSTOM_POST_TYPE}_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) to add the post meta support in WP Rest API for any post type.

Check the Gist [search post by post meta with rest API](https://gist.github.com/maheshwaghmare/0bbe5eabceed24aa76ef1eabe684a748).

**How to use?**

`http://example.org/wp-json/wp/v2/post?meta_key=<my_meta_key>&meta_value=<my_meta_value>`

**Example**

Get posts which post meta `already-visited` value is `true`.

`http://example.org/wp-json/wp/v2/post?meta_key=already-visited&meta_value=true`

It ONLY lists the posts which post meta key `already-visited` have value `true`.

For reference [Search post by post meta with rest api](https://maheshwaghmare.wordpress.com/2018/06/05/search-post-by-post-meta-with-rest-api/).

**Available Filters**

- rest_post_query
- rest_page_query
- rest_attachment_query

Comment: Thank you for this! This should more likely be the accepted answer I believe.

Comment: what about strings if we want a field with value (not null) i can retrieve latitude fields that greater that a value filter[meta_key]=latitude&filter[meta_compare]=%3C&filter[meta_value]=34.7 but i need another string field so i want to have which has value

Answer (score 5):

The following code should add multiple meta queries capability to all your post types. It supports CPT (Custom Post Type) and ACF (Advanced Custom Field). Source code also available on [Github](https://github.com/SK8-PTY-LTD/wp-rest-filter).

Add it to your function.php

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wp_rest_filter_add_filters' );
 /**
  * Add the necessary filter to each post type
  **/
function wp_rest_filter_add_filters() {
    foreach ( get_post_types( array( 'show_in_rest' => true ), 'objects' ) as $post_type ) {
        add_filter( 'rest_' . $post_type->name . '_query', 'wp_rest_filter_add_filter_param', 10, 2 );
    }
}
/**
 * Add the filter parameter
 *
 * @param  array           $args    The query arguments.
 * @param  WP_REST_Request $request Full details about the request.
 * @return array $args.
 **/
function wp_rest_filter_add_filter_param( $args, $request ) {
    // Bail out if no filter parameter is set.
    if ( empty( $request['filter'] ) || ! is_array( $request['filter'] ) ) {
        return $args;
    }
    $filter = $request['filter'];
    if ( isset( $filter['posts_per_page'] ) && ( (int) $filter['posts_per_page'] >= 1 && (int) $filter['posts_per_page'] <= 100 ) ) {
        $args['posts_per_page'] = $filter['posts_per_page'];
    }
    global $wp;
    $vars = apply_filters( 'rest_query_vars', $wp->public_query_vars );
    function allow_meta_query( $valid_vars )
    {
        $valid_vars = array_merge( $valid_vars, array( 'meta_query', 'meta_key', 'meta_value', 'meta_compare' ) );
        return $valid_vars;
    }
    $vars = allow_meta_query( $vars );

    foreach ( $vars as $var ) {
        if ( isset( $filter[ $var ] ) ) {
            $args[ $var ] = $filter[ $var ];
        }
    }
    return $args;
}
```

IMHO, a more better way would to include the additional function as a seperate plugin. So even when user changed theme, your api calls won't be affected.

Therefore I've developed a **plugin** for meta query in WordPress. Better yet, it supports ACF too!

[WP REST Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-filter/)

After installation, just do a **GET** request in the following format.

```
https://domain.com/wp-json/acf/v3/customposttype?filter[meta_key]=acfkey&filter[meta_value]=acfvalue
```

Check out the plugin source code from [Github](https://github.com/SK8-PTY-LTD/wp-rest-filter).

Comment: Nice plugin, however date sorting doesnt work for acf date fields!

Comment: Hi Tanckom. Thank you for your message. Can you please elaborate your issue? What have you tried? Please submit your issue to https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-rest-filter. Our support team will get back to your there. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Jack,
I figured out that the correct url to grab the date from acf field and sort it by asc or desc is following:
https://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/events?filter[meta_key].acf=evt_date&per_page=100&filter[order]=asc

Comment: Awesome! Glad our plugin helped! :D

Comment: It really did, keep up the good work! :)

Comment: One single question, how would i filter for dates in this format "2018-09-25 19:30:00 GMT+02:00". Date and Time picker for ACF doesnt allow ISO format :(
I tried this but without success domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/events?filter[meta_key].acf=date&[meta_value]=2018-09-25

Comment: Convert to GMT time, yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss , then domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/events?filter[meta_key]=date&[meta_value]=2018-09-25T23:59:59. I believe ACF saves data in IOS format in the MySQL, so It should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's impossible to get the Date and Time without spaces with the Add-on plugin for ACF "Date and Time Picker" :/ That's why I had to to this way.

Comment: We can help with that. Please send us an email with the detail of the issue to hi@sk8.tech. We'll get back to you asap.