# Rest Api v2 orderby meta_key in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, rest-api

I get my posts of an cpt like this:
http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/cpt

at this posts there are shown post_meta values.

Does anyone know a way to order the posts by the meta like this:
http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/cpt?orderby=my_meta_field

I found some solutions, but none of them are working for me….
Please help!
Thanks! Stefan

Answer (score 2):

You can use this filter to change order :

```
$type = "cptCode";

add_filter("rest_" . $type . "_query", function ($args, $query) {

    $args["orderby"] = "meta_value";
    $args["meta_key"] = "my_meta_field";

    return $args;

}, 10, 2);
```

You can also test `$_GET` to change the order conditionally.

Comment: thank you for your answer! This would be a nice one for me but it doesn´t work...after I copied this to funkctions.php and entered ".../v2/cpt?filter[orderby]=myfield" I dont get the solution...do I something wrong? :/

Answer (score 1):

Since wordpress 4.7, it has build in Rest Api 2. And since then there is no args like that. 
So you can write your own endopint and create what you want.

Check out answer: 
[How to do a meta query using REST-API in WordPress 4.7+?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271877/how-to-do-a-meta-query-using-rest-api-in-wordpress-4-7)

Or use: https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter

Comment: thanks for your answer! The Plugin doesn´t work for me :/ I think I have to build my own controller class ...I thought there would exist a 3 line Code to activate these funkction :D