# ACF orderby not sorting dates correctly

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, rest-api

I have created a simple headless WP REST API to manage some data to an app I am creating. Per [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284719/rest-api-v2-orderby-meta-key-in-custom-post-type?newreg=84b2a178afe148aaa04a07192c2e98ea) I have implemented that filter plugin to re-allow filtering with ACF and the REST API. Therefore, I am able to create a query that sorts the data (note that I am using custom post types as well as custom fields) via title like so:
`?filter[meta_key]=title&filter[order]=DESC`

But if I try literally any other field, it gives very inconsistent sorting. The biggest issue is trying to sort via dates.
`?filter[meta_key]=release_date&filter[order]=DESC`

The goal is to do this by only using plugins so that I can focus on any code I write being in the app itself and manage the plugins and leave the rest of the WP instance alone. Therefore I'd prefer a solution that is plugin based or requires forking/editing a plugin. Perhaps I'm just trying to filter things improperly.

I use the following plugins (amongst a few unrelated plugins):

Advanced Custom Fields PRO

ACF to REST API

Custom Post Types UI

WP REST API Controller

WP REST API filter parameter

EDIT: After reviewing this some more, I realize now that the FILTER plugin from the post mentioned above doesn't seem to be working and therefore ACF orderby doesn't work. Is there any way to re-enable `orderby` with ACF via plugin?

Comment: if you need data to be formatted in some specific way you should simply write your own end point

Comment: @MarkKaplun Sorry, I'm not sure what you're referencing. The issue is improper sorting, not data formatting.

The dates are returned in YYYYMMDD format which should be easily sortable, but the filter/orderby params don't seem to be working properly with ACF fields. Figured this was surely an issue that someone else had encountered but it doesn't seem to be the case :(

Comment: let me try again, if you need anything that is not supported by the official API "out of the box", you should write your own end point.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I guess. Just figured this would be a more common issue and that someone would have encountered it before and tried a common solution instead of thousands of people adding their own snippets to WP. WP dev at its best, I suppose.

Comment: you are using a plugin (actually two) and the quirks of it are outside of the scope of this site.

Comment: Mark, I don't really understand why asking about the quirks of one of the most commonly used WP plugins in combination with the natural WP REST API is out of scope for a stack exchange specifically about WP development. I think this is exactly the place to ask such questions.

Comment: well, maybe it is time for you to read the help section pf this site to learn what is on and off topic

Comment: Thanks for your valuable and constructive contribution, Mark. It's people like you that give stack exchanges and internet forums in general such a good reputation.

Comment: we are doing all we can to help freeloaders that spend very little time contributing but a lot of time complaining.

Answer (score 1):

What "return format" do you have set in ACF for the date field? Sorting by numbers produces unexpected results when you use "d/m/Y" or "m/d/Y". If you instead choose "Ymd" as in "20180221" for the return format, you'll get an integer that's sortable in the expected way.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add this to the OP and forgot. I do have it in Ymd which is why I expected it to work.

I realize now after trying a few more things that for some reason none of the ACF fields are working, note just the date, and that this isn't a date specific issue.

Comment: ACF doesn't expose itself in the REST API by default - you'll need another plugin for that: https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/

Comment: Thanks Elaine, I do have the ACF to REST API plugin included. The ACF fields appear in the REST API but they do not get sorted properly via the `orderby` filters that I use. I also know that `filter` doesn't work by default anymore, so I used another plugin (WP REST API filter parameter) to re-enable this. This allowed the `title` to be sorted via `orderby` but it doesn't seem to sort properly for any of the ACF fields.