# How to add a custom parameter to a WP API default route?

Tags: api

I have created an `opps` custom post type and registered a custom API field of `closed` for it with the following code:

```
public function get_opp_state() {
    register_rest_field( 'opps', 'closed', array(
        'get_callback' => array( $this, 'get_opp_state_callback' ),
        'update_callback' => null,
        'schema' => null
    ));        
} 

public function get_opp_state_callback( $opp ) {  
    $oppDeadline = get_field( 'deadline', $opp[ 'id' ] ); 
    $today = date( 'Ymd' );
    $isClosed = $oppDeadline < $today; 
    return $isClosed;            
}
```

To retrieve all posts that use the `opps` post type, I use this request:

> http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/opps

Now how can I extend that request to only fetch `opps` posts that have a `closed` field equal to true? I was hoping the following would work, but it  doesn't:

> http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/opps?closed=true

I know I can create a custom route, but I really would like to avoid that since the information returned by the default request has all the info I need (except for that `closed` field). So is there any way to achieve this without a custom route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of digging I seem to have found a solution myself, and a pretty powerful one, which makes use of a `rest_{ post_type }_query` filter (replace the { post_type } part with the slug of your custom post type. You can use `rest_post_query` to alter the default `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` request):

```
public function __construct() {  
    // Make sure you add those numbers at the end of the line, or it won't work
    add_filter( 'rest_opps_query', array( $this, 'get_opps_by_state' ), 10, 2 );  
}  
       
public function get_opps_by_state( $args, $request ) {

    $state = $request->get_param( 'state' );  

    if( $state == 'open' ) {
        $args[ 'meta_query' ] = array(
            'deadline' => array(
                'key' => 'deadline',
                'value' => date( 'Ymd' ), 
                'compare' => '>',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            )
        );
    } elseif ( $state == 'closed' ) {
        $args[ 'meta_query' ] = array(
            'deadline' => array(
                'key' => 'deadline',
                'value' => date( 'Ymd' ), 
                'compare' => '<',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            )
        );
    }

    return $args; 

}
```

So now I can use the default Wordpress API route to fetch custom posts:

> http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/opps

and filter its results based on my custom parameter, `status`:

> http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/opps?status=open
>
> http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/opps?status=closed

No custom routes needed!

Comment: It's interesting how little documentation or references there are to implementing a custom parameter on top of existing REST routes/controllers - even now, three years after this answer was posted. I would have thought it to be a much more routine procedure. Thank you for digging this up :)

Answer (score 0):

When modifying a REST request, you have [2 options](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/),
 - register a field, like you have done, only adds a key:value pair to the json object.
 - register a meta, which allows the addition of a custom meta-field to the json object.

When you make a custom request with,

`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=my_page`

for example, you are actually query a field of the post, in this case the `slug`.

When you do,

`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/opps?closed=true`

you are attempting to query a field called `closed` which does not exists since it has only been added as a key and not a meta-field to the json response.

I think your best option is still a [custom route](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271877/how-to-do-a-meta-query-using-rest-api-in-wordpress-4-7#answer-271887)