# Add custom parameter to REST API request of a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api, parameter

I registered a custom post type called `wasb_message` with `show_in_rest` set to `true` and `rest_base` set to `'messages'` so the resource is reachable at endpoint *https://mydomain/wp-json/wp/v2/messages* (using the `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` class).
The custom post type has a custom meta field called `wasb_status` with an integer value, how can I add a custom parameter so when I do a get request to endpoint *https://mydomain/wp-json/wp/v2/messages?status=2* I retrieve messages with `wasb_status` equal to 2 without register a new route?

I read [this code reference page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) and [this old question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300316/how-to-add-a-custom-parameter-to-a-wp-api-default-route) but I can't get it working, using Postman to send get request I get:

```
{
    "code": "rest_invalid_param",
    "message": "Parametro(i) non valido(i): status",
    "data": {
        "status": 400,
        "params": {
            "status": "Stato non consentito."
        },
        "details": {
            "status": {
                "code": "rest_forbidden_status",
                "message": "Stato non consentito.",
                "data": {
                    "status": 401
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved following [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300316/how-to-add-a-custom-parameter-to-a-wp-api-default-route) and writing:

```
public function query_wasb_messages_by_status( $args, $request ) {

        if ( ! is_null( $request->get_param( 'message_status' ) ) ) {
            $args['meta_query'] = array(
                '_wasb_message_status' => array(
                    'key'     => '_wasb_message_status',
                    'value'   => (int) $request->get_param( 'message_status' ),
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'type'    => 'numeric'
                )
            );
        }

        return $args;

    }
add_filter( 'rest_wasb_message_query', array( $this, 'query_wasb_messages_by_status'), 10, 2 );
```

My problem is I used `status` as parameter name but `status` already exists for posts ('draft', 'published', etc...) so I changed the name to `message_status`...

Answer (score 0):

As per the reply by Haris it should be something like this:

```
function wasb_rest_parameter($args, $request) {
    if( isset($request["wasb_status"]) && is_numeric($request["wasb_status"]) ) {
        $args['meta_key'] = 'wasb_status';
        $args['meta_value'] = intval($request["wasb_status"]);
    }       
 
    return $args;
}
add_filter('rest_wasb_message_query', 'wasb_rest_parameter', 10, 2);
```

Not yet tested. If it does not work, will update the answer.