# meta_query with standard getEntityRecords possible?

Tags: block-editor, rest-api

in my custom block I'm trying to display post-type-items that in php are selected with a meta query. Since I needed to compare the meta value to a date and I eventually resorted to creating and using a custom rest endpoint for the block (which had its own challenges, includig a bug-like lack of documentation: see https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/25388 ).

But I'm wondering if there isn't a simpler method for achieving this?

I understand (see code below) I can extend the standard getEntityRecords query by adding keys and values, but is there by now also a way to actually run a meta query that allows to compare values, using standard query params?

I couldn't find any info in that regard, but maybe someone here is aware of a simpler method for running a meta query than creating a custom rest endpoint.

Thanks!

```
add_filter(
    'rest_POSTTYPE_query',
    function( $args, $request ) {
        if ( $meta_key = $request->get_param( 'metaKey' ) ) {
            $args['meta_key']   = $meta_key;
            $args['meta_value'] = $request->get_param( 'metaValue' );
        }
        return $args;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that's still not possible. `getEntityRecords()` uses the REST API, but [that doesn't support meta queries by default](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#what-happened-to-the-filter-query-parameter). You can follow ticket [#47194](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47194) if you'd like to keep tabs on the request to add support, or contribute to it.

For now, [using `rest_{posttype}_query`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/305337/3898) seems to be the conventional way to achieve what you want. I'd recommend that over creating a custom endpoint.

Don't forget that [you'll need to register the meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#using-register_rest_field-vs-register_meta) if you also want to see it in the *response*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link! 

Since you say that `rest_{posttype}_query` would be the standard way to do this - maybe I'm just lacking the imagination, but how would I include a date comparison in a function filtered by `rest_{posttype}_query`? Am I wrong in the assumption that the filter will only add meta keys and values to the query (and thus allow to include/exclude records based on specific values but that it won't allow to add comparisons/operations to the query that would in turn allow something like "datekey/datevalue" > "today"?

Comment: You should be able to add [anything that `WP_Query` supports](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters). The simple way would be using `meta_compare`. If you need to add multiple comparisons, you can have your filter callback setup a `meta_query` array.

Comment: The names of the parameters in your REST request are arbitrary, so anything will work as long as your filter callback maps them to the appropriate `WP_Query` parameters. In fact, it's probably a good idea to prefix them with your plugin slug, just in case Core starts allowing meta fields in native requests in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional info =)